# Firma con canvas, se reemplaza la imagen al guardar

Tags: php, ajax, canvas, base64

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy guardando una firma que realizo con canvas en el html, la tomo con ajax y la mando a php. Se guarda bien, le pongo el nombre de la imagen la fecha del dia y el id de la persona. El id de la persona lo toma al hacer click buscar en un input donde capturo el id de la persona. Hasta aqui todo bien.
El problema viene cuando, busco un id, capturo el id, voy al canvas, hago la firma, la guardo y se guarda bien, pero cuando ahi mismo sin regrescar la pagina, busco otro id en el input buscar, abro el canvas para firmar y envio la imagen, crea otro archivo con la fecha y el id muy bien, pero la imagen= es decir, la dataURI que convierto a base 64, al parecer se esta repitiendo con la anterior, porque reemplaza la primera firma y se guarda la ultima firma en las dos imagenes

```
      <?php 


        if(isset($_POST["identificacion"])){

        $identificacion = $_POST["identificacion"];
           guardarImagen($identificacion);

           }


         function guardarImagen($identificacion){

           $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];

         // Imagen base64 enviada desde javascript en el formulario
      $baseFromJavascript = $_POST['dataUrl'];;

         // Nuestro base64 contiene un esquema Data URI (data:image/png;base64,)
          // que necesitamos remover para poder guardar nuestra imagen
         // Usa explode para dividir la cadena de texto en la , (coma)
          $base_to_php = explode(',', $baseFromJavascript);
         // El segundo item del array base_to_php contiene la información que necesitamos (base64 
          plano)
          // y usar base64_decode para obtener la información binaria de la imagen
        $data = base64_decode($base_to_php[1]);// BBBFBfj42Pj4....

            // Proporciona una locación a la nueva imagen (con el nombre y formato especifico)
         $filepath = '../../resources/firmas/'.$fecha.$identificacion.'.png'; // or image.jpg

             // Finalmente guarda la imágen en el directorio especificado y con la informacion dada
          $guardarimagen = file_put_contents($filepath, $data);

      if($guardarimagen){

        echo "se guardo la imagen";
      
limpiar($identificacion,$fecha,$baseFromJavascript,$base_to_php,$data,$filepath,$guardarimagen);
 
     }

  }

          function limpiar(){
      unset($identificacion,$fecha,$baseFromJavascript,$base_to_php,$data,$filepath,$guardarimagen);

     }
```

Porque se estaria reemplazando la imagen de la primera imagen con la ultima, o segunda que se realiza.

Debugee lo que viene de ajax y viene la imagen diferente, pero al debuguear lo que guardo en php, la imagen son las mismas.

Cabe destacar que esto solo ocurre cuando envio la primera firma, y sin recargar la pagina, capturo otro id y realizo otra firma. Pero al realizar la primera firma, y recargo la pagina, funciona con normalidad sin sobreescribirse la imagen anterior. funciona bien. Por eso intente cada vez que se guarda la imagen en el directorio hacerle unset(a las variables). Asi limpio lo que viene siempre. Pero sigue reemplazando la imagen ("no el nombre de la imagen png")

Es como que se guarda la primera, y si lo hago sin recargar la pagina y cargo otro id y otra firma, toma los datos de la primera tambien, y modifica el contenido(imagen) de la primera y tambien inserta la segunda:

la segunda imagen reemplazo a la primera imagen de la izquierda

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo solucione colocando una bandera en

```
file_put_contents($filepath, $data);
```

le coloque la bandera

```
file_put_contents($filepath, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```